# Which is the best way of including one class object insider another class in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose a class A object should be part of a class B, then I have three ways of incorporating it insider class B:

```
Method 1:
    class B
    {
     public:
          B():objA() {};
          ~B() {};
          A objA;    
    };


Method 2:  
    class B
    {
     public:
          B():pobjA(0) {};
          ~B() { delete pobjA;}
          A *pobjA;    
    };
Method 3:
    class C
    {
     public:
           B() {};
           ~B() {};
           boost::shared_ptr<A> pObjA;
    };
```

Then my question is: are there some guidelines I can follow when I put object A as part of Class B. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to include a class object in another class is method 1. The other methods do something totally different.

Comment: Don't forget your `;` after each class declaration.

Comment: Also you don't need to check pobjA for "not-nullness" before you attempt `delete`: `delete` on NULL is mandated by the standard to be benign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the object to be dinamically allocated when A is created then go for a dynamic **new** when you repute it is necessary. In that case remember to garbabe-collect with **delete** your object when A is destroyed otherwise you're gonna leak memory.

Using boost::shared_ptr takes care of garbage collection so you can skip the "delete" phase as long as you control the scope where the pointer is collected (nb. your code is bugged in the second step, you need to allocate before deallocate the object somehow)

The first method always allocates an object within the parent object's memory layout and frees it as the object is destroyed. Notice that you don't need the default constructor call in the initialization list if you have a no-arguments default constructor (or a default one)

Answer (score 1):

If there's no reason to use a pointer, don't use a pointer: I'd go with the first option. Also notice that your RAII in the second example is completely broken, as it does not follow the rule of three.

If you need dynamic allocation you can use the third with `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the distinction between [association, aggregation, and composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265711/association-aggregation-and-composition), and when it is appropriate to use them. There is no generic answer to that except for using the weakest relationship you can get away with. As far as using smart pointers, you would probably use them anywhere you'd otherwise use raw pointers but want to manage ownership more cleanly. The con to that is the overhead, the pro is the neatness.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition to others:
If you care for compilation speed - go with [pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/). 
In your case it should be Method 3 (I would prefer unique_ptr though).